# Text processing: find a match in the middle of the line and then print that one and line before

Tags: ksh, aix

I would like to search all of the lines for 2019 year and beyond, but only after "To:" string. Anything between "From:" and "To:" is not relevant.

I have tried using grep with -A -B options, but grep on AIX doesn't have that options. 
Also I've tried something like but I can't figure out how to print line before the match, and how to search for a pattern in the middle of the line.

awk '$13 >= 2019 {print $0}' file.txt

In the end I would like to search for "2019" on every line, behind "To:" string.
For example output would look something like this:

certificate4 - From: Friday, October 16, 2009 1:22:18 PM CEST To: Wednesday, October 16, 2019 1:32:16 PM CEST

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but according to your example, that awk code is working providing you are testing $15 instead of $13.

Comment: If you want to use `grep`, prepend `To:.*` to the pattern, e.g. `To:.*2019`

Comment: see [How to produce a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); in particular, provide some sample data, the expected output, and what you've tried so far (and the resulting output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing at what the OP has in mind:

- if a line includes the string 'To:' and
- the line also has a number in field #15 that is >= 2019 then
- print the previous line and the current line

And some assumptions:

- first line in file could match
- consecutive lines could match the 'To:/>=2019' search:
- for all lines of interest the 'To' comes before field #15

Sample data based solely on the one line provided by OP:

```
$ cat -n print15.dat
 1  certificate1 - From: Friday, October 16, 2009 1:22:18 PM CEST To: Wednesday, October 16, 2019 1:32:16 PM CEST
 2  this is line two
 3  this is line three
 4  certificate4 - From: Friday, October 16, 2009 1:22:18 PM CEST To: Wednesday, October 16, 2019 1:32:16 PM CEST
 5  this is line five
 6  this is line six
 7  certificate7 - From: Friday, October 16, 2020 1:22:18 PM CEST To: Wednesday, October 16, 2017 1:32:16 PM CEST
 8  this is line eight
 9  this is line nine
10  certificate10 - From: Friday, October 16, 2009 1:22:18 PM CEST To: Wednesday, October 16, 2020 1:32:16 PM CEST
11  this is line eleven
12  certificate12 - From: Friday, October 16, 2009 1:22:18 PM CEST To: Wednesday, October 16, 2023 1:32:16 PM CEST
13  certificate13 - From: Friday, October 16, 2009 1:22:18 PM CEST To: Wednesday, October 16, 2024 1:32:16 PM CEST
14  this is line fourteen
```

Applying the described logic we see that lines 1, 4, 10, 12 and 13 match 'To:./>=2019'.

One `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '/To:/ && $15 >= 2019 { printf "\n#############\n"
                              if (length(prevline) > 0) { print prevline }
                              print $0
                              printf   "#############\n"
                            }
                            { prevline=$0 }
' print15.dat
```

Explanation:

- `/To:/ && $15 >= 2019` : matches any line with the patterns 'To:' and field #15 >= 2019  (granted, this doesn't enforce that 'To:' comes before field #15)
- `print/########` : simple header/trailer to visibly distinguish between sets of matching rows
- `if/length/print` : if prevline is non empty then print it
- `print $0` : print current line (that matches 'To:' and $15>=2019)
- `prevline=$0` : set our 'prevline' variable to the current line (to be used as 'previous line' for the next line we process)

And the output:

```
#############
certificate1 - From: Friday, October 16, 2009 1:22:18 PM CEST To: Wednesday, October 16, 2019 1:32:16 PM CEST
#############

#############
this is line three
certificate4 - From: Friday, October 16, 2009 1:22:18 PM CEST To: Wednesday, October 16, 2019 1:32:16 PM CEST
#############

#############
this is line nine
certificate10 - From: Friday, October 16, 2009 1:22:18 PM CEST To: Wednesday, October 16, 2020 1:32:16 PM CEST
#############

#############
this is line eleven
certificate12 - From: Friday, October 16, 2009 1:22:18 PM CEST To: Wednesday, October 16, 2023 1:32:16 PM CEST
#############

#############
certificate12 - From: Friday, October 16, 2009 1:22:18 PM CEST To: Wednesday, October 16, 2023 1:32:16 PM CEST
certificate13 - From: Friday, October 16, 2009 1:22:18 PM CEST To: Wednesday, October 16, 2024 1:32:16 PM CEST
#############
```

Comment: This explanation was amazingly detailed and thank you so much for it. It was exactly what I was looking for.
Sorry for the typo, correct field is $15 not $13 as I wrote.